# any performance penalto to be expected with thread_local?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, thread-local-storage

Using C++11 and/or C11 `thread_local`, should we expect any performance penalty over non-`thread_local` storage on x86 (32- or 64-bit) Linux, Red Hat 5 or newer, with a recent g++/gcc (say, version 4 or newer) or clang?

Comment: Performance penalty compared to what?

Comment: compared to non-thread_local storage.  I've attempted to clarify.

Comment: That's a bit like asking if a static member variable is slower/faster than a non-static one. They don't do the same thing. You'll need more details on your exact scenario. (And as always - you'll need to benchmark for your specific case anyway.)

Comment: Static and non-static performance should be the same, depending only whether they're in L1, L2, L3 cache or main memory, and whether subject to false-sharing, no?

Comment: storage *duration* has little to do with storage *perfomance*

Comment: If you're saying the answer to my question is no, @Caleth, why not just answer the question?

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 18.04 x86_64 with gcc-8.3 (options `-pthread -m{arch,tune}=native -std=gnu++17 -g -O3 -ffast-math -falign-{functions,loops}=64 -DNDEBUG`) the difference is almost imperceptible:

```
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>

struct A { static unsigned n; };
unsigned A::n = 0;

struct B { static thread_local unsigned n; };
thread_local unsigned B::n = 0;

template<class T>
void bm(benchmark::State& state) {
    for(auto _ : state)
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(++T::n);
}

BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(bm, A);
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(bm, B);
BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

Results:

```
Run on (16 X 5000 MHz CPU s)
CPU Caches:
  L1 Data 32 KiB (x8)
  L1 Instruction 32 KiB (x8)
  L2 Unified 256 KiB (x8)
  L3 Unified 16384 KiB (x1)
Load Average: 0.59, 0.49, 0.38
-----------------------------------------------------
Benchmark           Time             CPU   Iterations
-----------------------------------------------------
bm<A>            1.09 ns         1.09 ns    642390002
bm<B>            1.09 ns         1.09 ns    633963210
```

On x86_64 `thread_local` variables are accessed relative to `fs` register. Instructions with such addressing mode are often 2 bytes longer, so theoretically, they can take more time.

On other platforms it depends on how access to `thread_local` variables is implemented. See [ELF Handling For Thread-Local Storage](https://akkadia.org/drepper/tls.pdf) for more details.

Comment: Thx Maxim!  So it seems like the benchmarks are within a percent, but the extra two bytes have no effect when with such a small amount of code?  I would have expected more effect from them.

Comment: Any need for the thread_local before unsigned _within_ struct B?

Comment: @SwissFrank `thread_local` is required at both declaration and definition.

Comment: OK, I see, in B n is a static thread_local member, which you then init to 0.  I read too fast.